# How can I see which set of backups Déjà-Dup has already saved?

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

I've been using `Déjà-dup` for a while with good moments and bad moments (backup failed to complete for some unknown reason, there is already a bug report for this).

So, I would like to check which sets of backup I have already successfully made, which files are included, when they were saved (it would be great to be able to see each single version of the file, but I'd be quite happy to see which date is latest successful backed up version).

Is there a tool that could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *System settings*, select *Back up* and get in to the program. 
Click *Restore* and a new window will be opened which is asking "Restore from where?"
Select your own back up location and click Forward. After a short analyse, you will be able to see the dropdown list of the avaliable dates.